# Get size/length of a value in a HashMap

Tags: java, size, hashmap

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

How do I get the size/length of matching value's at the String?

example:

1 , Red
2 , Red
3 , Blue
4 , Blue
5 , Red

Size of the String of RED = 3

Comment: What do you mean by "second" here? HashMaps are unordered.

Comment: @ JonSkeet Edited, made a little mistake.

Comment: So you're looking for the frequency of a particular value in the map?

Comment: Im looking for that amount of RED's in the String Values. and this place 3 times.

Comment: So both answers that aren't mine look correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`.values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) to get a collection containing all the values of the hash map, and then use [`Collections.frequency()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29) to count the number of objects in the collection.

```
return Collections.frequency(map.values(), "red");
```

Comment: I didn't knew this one... I wonder why they decided to put all those methods which have so little use... Java standard API are less and less simple and canonical...

Answer (score 0):

Or do you mean the count?

If so call

```
map.values()
```

to get a list of the values.

Then you can iterate through it and count how many time RED appears